# Adding different text formats like (Bold, Underline, color, etc) inside DrawString, PDFSharp

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I need to change the DrawString paragraph into different file formats like (Bold, Underline, color, etc).
Eg: Hi, This *is* **RAM**,

```
 gfx.DrawString("Hi, This is RAM", fontRegular, XBrushes.DarkSlateGray, 0, 30);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DrawString` with regular, bold, italic, and bold italic fonts.

There are no paragraphs with PDFsharp. Just make the appropriate calls to `DrawString` with the right fonts and the correct positions. With your example, you need three calls to `DrawString`. Use `MeasureString` to find how much space a string needs so you can draw the next string at the correct position.

MigraDoc uses PDFsharp to create PDF files. MigraDoc has paragraphs and using `AddFormattedText` you can mix several fonts and font styles in one paragraph. So maybe consider using MigraDoc.

Information about MigraDoc on the PDFsharp web site:
http://pdfsharp.net/Overview.ashx

Comment: Hi, I am getting the version conflict error, can you mention the version for PDFsharp and MigraDoc.

Comment: Download the MigraDoc NuGet package and remove the PDFsharp NuGet package, and the conflict will be gone. MigraDoc includes the appropriate version of PDFsharp. Include "Prereleases" to get MigraDoc 1.50 beta 4c.